# Python add columns to DataFame with rolling window based on 3 previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, shift

I have a dataframe like this:

```
original = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"])
print(original)

   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month
0      50       17        55
1      45        3        10
2      93       79        84
3      99       38        33
4      44       35        35
5      25       43        87
6      38       88        56
7      20       66         6
8       4       23         6
9      39       75         3
```

I need to generate new dataframe starting from 3rd row of `original` dataframe and add new 9 columns based on rolling window defined as 3 previous rows with corresponding prefixes: [_0,_1, _2]. So, It's rows with index [0,1,2] from `original` dataframe . 
For example, the next 3 columns will be from the `original.iloc[0]`, 
and after the next 3 columns will be from the `original.iloc[1]`, 
and the last 3 columns will be from the `original.iloc[2]`

I tried to solve it by the next code:

```
    subset_shifted = original[["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"]].shift(3)
    subset_shifted.columns = ["P1_day_0", "P1_week_0", "P1_month_0"]
    original_ = pd.concat([original, subset_shifted], axis = 1)
    print(original_)
```

In result, I Have 3 additional columns with value from the previous 0 row:

```
   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month  P1_day_0  P1_week_0  P1_month_0
0      50       17        55       NaN        NaN         NaN
1      45        3        10       NaN        NaN         NaN
2      93       79        84       NaN        NaN         NaN
3      99       38        33      50.0       17.0        55.0
4      44       35        35      45.0        3.0        10.0
5      25       43        87      93.0       79.0        84.0
6      38       88        56      99.0       38.0        33.0
7      20       66         6      44.0       35.0        35.0
8       4       23         6      25.0       43.0        87.0
9      39       75         3      38.0       88.0        56.0
```

In the next iteration I did `shift(2)` with the same approach and received the columns from the `original.iloc[1]`.
On the last iteration I did  `shift(1)` and got expected result in view of:

```
 result = original_.iloc[3:]

   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month  P1_day_0  P1_week_0  P1_month_0  P1_day_1  P1_week_1  P1_month_1  P1_day_2  P1_week_2  P1_month_2
3      99       38        33      50.0       17.0        55.0      45.0        3.0        10.0      93.0       79.0        84.0
4      44       35        35      45.0        3.0        10.0      93.0       79.0        84.0      99.0       38.0        33.0
5      25       43        87      93.0       79.0        84.0      99.0       38.0        33.0      44.0       35.0        35.0
6      38       88        56      99.0       38.0        33.0      44.0       35.0        35.0      25.0       43.0        87.0
7      20       66         6      44.0       35.0        35.0      25.0       43.0        87.0      38.0       88.0        56.0
8       4       23         6      25.0       43.0        87.0      38.0       88.0        56.0      20.0       66.0         6.0
9      39       75         3      38.0       88.0        56.0      20.0       66.0         6.0       4.0       23.0         6.0
```

Question: 
Is there any way to solve this task with better approach as I described? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using jupyter. Why don't you do `print(some_data_frame)` and copy/paste the text? They look much better than images.

Comment: @QuangHoang, yes I use ```Jupyter```. Thank you for an idea. In the future I'll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want all these extra DataFrames, you could just add the new columns to your orignal df directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), 
    columns=["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"],
)

original[
    ["P1_day_0", "P1_week_0", "P1_month_0"]
] = original[
    ["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"]
].shift(3)

print(original)
```

output:

```
   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month  P1_day_0  P1_week_0  P1_month_0
0       2       35        26       NaN        NaN         NaN
1      99        4        96       NaN        NaN         NaN
2       4       67         6       NaN        NaN         NaN
3      76       33        31       2.0       35.0        26.0
4      84       60        98      99.0        4.0        96.0
5      57        1        58       4.0       67.0         6.0
6      35       70        96      76.0       33.0        31.0
7      81       32        39      84.0       60.0        98.0
8      25        4        38      57.0        1.0        58.0
9      83        4        60      35.0       70.0        96.0
```

[python tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0Aoriginal%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20np.random.randint%280,100,size%3D%2810,%203%29%29,%20%0A%20%20%20%20columns%3D%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D,%0A%29%0A%0Aoriginal%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22P1_day_0%22,%20%22P1_week_0%22,%20%22P1_month_0%22%5D%0A%5D%20%3D%20original%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D%0A%5D.shift%283%29%0A%0Aprint%28original%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit: OP asked the follow up question:

> yes, for the first row it makes sense. But, my task is to add first 3 rows with index 0-1-2 as new 9 columns for the respected rows started from 3rd index. In your output row with index 1st is not added to the 3rd row as 3 columns. In my code that's why I used shift(2) and shift(1) iteratively.

Here is how this could be done iteratively:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), 
    columns=["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"],
)

for shift, n in ((3,0),(2,1),(1,2)):
    original[
        [f"P1_day_{n}", f"P1_week_{n}", f"P1_month_{n}"]
    ] = original[
        ["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"]
    ].shift(shift)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(original.iloc[3:])
```

Output:

```
   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month  P1_day_0  P1_week_0  P1_month_0  P1_day_1  \
3      58       43        74      26.0       56.0        82.0      56.0   
4      44       27        40      56.0       87.0        38.0      31.0   
5       2       90         4      31.0       32.0        87.0      58.0   
6      90       70         6      58.0       43.0        74.0      44.0   
7       1       31        57      44.0       27.0        40.0       2.0   
8      96       22        69       2.0       90.0         4.0      90.0   
9      13       98        47      90.0       70.0         6.0       1.0   

   P1_week_1  P1_month_1  P1_day_2  P1_week_2  P1_month_2  
3       87.0        38.0      31.0       32.0        87.0  
4       32.0        87.0      58.0       43.0        74.0  
5       43.0        74.0      44.0       27.0        40.0  
6       27.0        40.0       2.0       90.0         4.0  
7       90.0         4.0      90.0       70.0         6.0  
8       70.0         6.0       1.0       31.0        57.0  
9       31.0        57.0      96.0       22.0        69.0
```

[python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0Aoriginal%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20np.random.randint%280,100,size%3D%2810,%203%29%29,%20%0A%20%20%20%20columns%3D%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D,%0A%29%0A%0Afor%20shift,%20n%20in%20%28%283,0%29,%282,1%29,%281,2%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20original%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bf%22P1_day_%7Bn%7D%22,%20f%22P1_week_%7Bn%7D%22,%20f%22P1_month_%7Bn%7D%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%20%3D%20original%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D.shift%28shift%29%0A%0Apd.set_option%28'display.max_columns',%20None%29%0Aprint%28original.iloc%5B3%3A%5D%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit 2: Not to make any assumptions here, but if your end goal is to get something like the 4 period moving average from the data in all of these new columns then you might not need them at all. You can use [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), 
    columns=["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"],
)

original[
    ["P1_day_4PMA", "P1_week_4PMA", "P1_month_4PMA"]
] = original[
    ["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"]
].rolling(4).mean()

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(original.iloc[3:])
```

Output:

```
   P1_day  P1_week  P1_month  P1_day_4PMA  P1_week_4PMA  P1_month_4PMA
3       1       13        48        31.25         38.00          55.00
4      10        4        40        22.00         21.00          45.75
5       7       76         0         5.50         23.75          37.00
6       5       69         9         5.75         40.50          24.25
7      63       31        82        21.25         45.00          32.75
8      26       67        22        25.25         60.75          28.25
9      89       41        40        45.75         52.00          38.25
```

[another python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0Aoriginal%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%0A%20%20%20%20np.random.randint%280,100,size%3D%2810,%203%29%29,%20%0A%20%20%20%20columns%3D%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D,%0A%29%0A%0Aoriginal%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22P1_day_4PMA%22,%20%22P1_week_4PMA%22,%20%22P1_month_4PMA%22%5D%0A%5D%20%3D%20original%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22P1_day%22,%20%22P1_week%22,%20%22P1_month%22%5D%0A%5D.rolling%284%29.mean%28%29%0A%0Apd.set_option%28'display.max_columns',%20None%29%0Aprint%28original.iloc%5B3%3A%5D%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: yes, for the first row it makes sense. But, my task is to add first 3 rows with index 0-1-2 as new 9 columns for the respected rows started from 3rd index. In your  output row with index 1st is not added to the 3rd row as 3 columns. In my code that's why I used ```shift(2)``` and ```shift(1)``` iteratively.

Comment: @Cindy I edited in an example for how you can do this itterativly for all 9 of those new columns.

Comment: Thanks that what I need. Your idea with ```for``` loop looks better than my version with ```for``` loop: 
    ```for shift_i in [3,2,1]: subset_shifted = original[columns].shift(shift_i) subset_shifted.columns = [s + str(shift_i) for s in columns]. original = pd.concat([original, subset_shifted], axis = 1)```

Comment: @Cindy Yupp! Tuple unpacking and f-strings are your friends. Learning how to use them will save you a lot of lines of code ;)

Comment: @Cindy I made another edit to my answer that you may want to look at. It kinda looks like you are setting to to find a moving average or some other rolling aggregate value for these columns, if that's the case then you might want to check out [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Comment: thanks for the new edit. No, I don't need average or aggregation for the added columns. My final goal is just extend item history with the history from the previous 3 months. Other words, item1 has history parameters started from 2019/01-2019/12 and for the last 9 months I need to add the history from the first 3 months in view of additional columns as I described in example.

Comment: @Cindy fair enough. best of luck in your Python adventures!

Comment: It helps to cut df on the first 3 months. Totally, there are 1000 unique items in df. And I have function for adding columns during the period of first 3 months. Last that what I do, ```result =original.groupby('Id').apply(get_additional_columns)```

Comment: Phillyclause89, thanks a lot for your code and ideas.